# LONG STRING with overlapping occurrences

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I've read lot of threads like this, but I didn't find any FAST solution: I have a string and I want to calculate the number of occurences of lots of sub-strings. I tried with this solution (I can't use any module, like re):

```
            if temp not in diz:
            diz[temp] = 0
            count = 0
            r = 0
            while True:
                r = txt.find(temp, r)
                if r >= 0:
                    r += 1
                    count += 1
                else:
                    diz[temp] += count
                    break
```

where **'**temp**'** is a string that contains the sub-string I want to get the number of occurences and **'**txt**'** is the main string.
This solution obviously works but when I check its efficiency using cProfile, it shows me that with very large strings, the find() method takes up to over 15s and I need to run the ENTIRE program in **1s <=** .

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
651113   17.180    0.000   17.180    0.000 {method 'find' of 'str' objects}
```

Do you have any possible solution? Thanks

Comment: the time limit is meaningless without giving a hint of the size of the input file (and the apporoximate number of matches).

Comment: I could say the largest string has 9600 characters and I need to find the number of occurences of at least 60 substrings, the given example of time limit refers to a string with 6100 characters and 40 substrings

Comment: why the requirement that you can not use `re`? this is a built-in module and probably an excellent fit for your use-case.

Comment: that's an assignment and it's specified to not use any module :/

Comment: Is it an assignment for an algorithms course? If so, the time limit will have been chosen in such a way that the straightforward algorithm you've tried would be too slow, and so encourage you to find a multiple string searching algorithm that does better.

Comment: no it is an assignment for a python course, and this is just a small part of the entire program to code, that's why i wrote that the entire program should run in 1s <=

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `str.count(substr)` method as:

```
txt.count(temp)
```

Believe me, it is ***very very fast***!

=====================

OR you could use an algorithm that I just thought of; could search `47` occurrences of the string `fvb@%^#` in a random string of `6100` characters in `~1.5ms`

```
def count_substrings(string, sub_str):
    count = 0
    first_sub_char = sub_str[0]
    sub_range = range(1, len(sub_str))
    for index in range(len(string)):
        if string[index] == first_sub_char:
            for sub_index in sub_range:
                if string[index + sub_index] != sub_str[sub_index]:
                    break
            else:
                count += 1
    return count
```

All it does is that go through each character of the original string and determine if it matches to the first character of the sub-string, and if yes then check that the next letters of the string also match the next characters of the sub-string; break the loop immediately if a non matching character is found and if the loop went unbroken; that means we found a clean match! then increment the counter.

*btw I am new to programming; please correct me, if i am wrong.*